# Reload config file for a background process

Tags: java

I have to reload a config file on demand while process is running in background.

- process should not be stopped and manually started after that.
- somehow I should ask for credentials or pass them to process

My idea is that I create a thread which is checking if config file is changed.
If this is the case:

- validate user (How to do that in a background process)
- do stuff which has to be done before config reload
- reload config

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Q1: how to ask for credentials in process
Q2: Is that approach OK?

Answer (score 1):

For checking which file is changed use the **WatchService**. Do not write your own thread for this.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html